# Oracle SQL - Round - Half

Tags: sql, oracle, rounding

Oracle ROUND function rounds "half up" by default :

```
select 3.674 my_number,
       round(3.674,2) round_on_number
from   dual
union
select 3.675 my_number,
       round(3.675,2) round_on_number
from   dual
union
select 3.676 my_number,
       round(3.676,2) round_on_number
from   dual
;

 MY_NUMBER ROUND_ON_NUMBER
---------- ---------------
     3,674            3,67
     3,675            3,68
     3,676            3,68
```

I need to round "half down", which essentially means that I should get the following result instead :

```
 MY_NUMBER EXPECTED_ROUND_ON_NUMBER
---------- ------------------------
     3,674                     3,67
     3,675                     3,67
     3,676                     3,68
```

It should be fast as I need to do this on millions of items.

I could probably detect if the number ends with a "5" and trunc that last digit in that case, round otherwise, but I have the feeling this will be inefficient (?)

Thank you !
David

Comment: [Take a look](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-nov/o61plsql-512011.html)

Comment: As there's no built-in function which does that, you'll end up with something like you described anyway. Though, as there are millions of rows, perhaps you could simply ROUND them all, and then fix only those *exceptions*.

Comment: that is also an option indeed, especially the rounding level is fixed and won't ever be changed (well, *should* never be). Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation [shows you the algorithm used](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ROUND-number.html):

> 1. If n is 0, then ROUND always returns 0 regardless of integer.
> 2. If n is negative, then ROUND(n, integer) returns -ROUND(-n, integer).
> 3. If n is positive, then
>      `ROUND(n, integer) = FLOOR(n * POWER(10, integer) + 0.5) * POWER(10, -integer)`

So you could modify the positive, non-zero version:

```
FLOOR(n * POWER(10, integer) + 0.4) * POWER(10, -integer)
                                 ^
```

e.g. for a fixed rounding, and ignoring zeros/negative for now:

```
with t (my_number) as (
  select 3.674 from dual
  union all select 3.675 from dual
  union all select 3.676 from dual
)
select my_number,
  floor(my_number * power(10, 2) + 0.4) * power(10, -2) as round_on_number
from  t;

 MY_NUMBER ROUND_ON_NUMBER
---------- ---------------
     3.674            3.67
     3.675            3.67
     3.676            3.68
```

You could include zero/negative via a case expression; or write your own function to handle it more neatly.

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you so much for this fast and useful answer, I helped me a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Knock .001 from the value, then round as normal:

```
select round(my_number-.001,2)
from MyTable
```

For rounding to 3dp, change to `-0.0001`, etc

Comment: Hi JohnHC, thank you too for this answer, it also works well, and is very simple. I will most probably go for the most complex, just because it looks closer to how the original ROUND function is implemented. Thank s!

Comment: @David - you should compare performance of both, particularly if you wrap mine in a function. (And either way, you need to decide how negative values should be handled.)

Comment: @AlexPoole has a much more robust approach. Mine is most definitely a quick fix.

Comment: I am actually implementing a billing validation service, "validating" is the ultimate goal. First I need to reverse-engineer the whole process. I did but one of the "conversion" I did not yet do is one of the rounding somewhere in the process. I first need to understand what rounding IS used to then code it in my validation service. I thought I had it right with the "rounding half-down", but as I implement solutions here on more items, I found this is not entirely true. It seems, despite the quality of answers here, I am one step back :-) Need to better understand what the rounding is first