# Round to .5 or 1.0 in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, rounding

I'm looking to round values like

2.39 -> 2.40

4.66 -> 4.70

2.11 -> 2.15

2.10 -> 2.10

2.50 -> 2.50

5.89 -> 5.90

How can I manage this in SQL?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48279641

Answer (score 2):

problem solved :

```
SELECT FLOOR ( (1.11 + 0.04) * 20) / 20 FROM DUAL;
```

test:

```
WITH t (my_number)
     AS (SELECT 3.1001 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2.39 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 4.66 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2.11 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2.10 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2.50 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 5.89 FROM DUAL)
SELECT my_number, FLOOR ( (my_number + 0.04) * 20) / 20 round_on_number
  FROM t;
```

```
3.1001  3.1
2.39    2.4
4.66    4.7
2.11    2.15
2.1     2.1
2.5     2.5
5.89    5.9
```

Comment: But your output is not as expected: for "2.39" it returning "2.4" but in you have mentioned in question it should return "2.5"??

Comment: sorry fixed 2.39 returning 2.40