# How to round number in PL-SQL?

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I want to round a number in PL-SQL.

the number:      56.84923552

expected round:  56.849236

I want to round the 6th digit after the point. How can I do this in sql developer (PL-SQL)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle SQL - Round - Half](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48279641/oracle-sql-round-half)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`round`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ROUND-number.html#GUID-849F6C45-0D72-4464-9C0F-8B6822BA85E1):

```
round(56.84923552, 6)
```

gives

```
56.849236
```